# MySQL update column in increment basis

Tags: mysql

```
I have MySQL table column as follows :

+------------+
|  auto_no   |
+------------+
| 2020-12750 |
| 2020-12751 |
| 2020-12752 |
| 2020-12753 |
| 2020-12754 |
+------------+
```

Then I need to update this column in increment basis using LIKE% format stating from 00001 as follows :

```
+------------+
|  auto_no   |
+------------+
| 2020-00001 |
| 2020-00002 |
| 2020-00003 |
| 2020-00004 |
| 2020-00005 |
+------------+
```

I tried the following:

```
update letter set auto_no = auto_no + auto_no LIKE %2020-%
```

But I think, this is not a correct way. May be used for loop. 
How can I change my query ?. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @  Tim Biegeleisen. To separate records relevant for the current year. All records starting from last year updated upto now

Comment: What's your server version?

Comment: @  Nick. MySQL 7+

Comment: @MCITTrends The error message you pasted under my answer says you are using MariaDB.  There is no MySQL 7.  What is your database?

Comment: @  Tim Biegeleisen. MySQL

Comment: `SELECT VERSION()` <-- What does this say?

Comment: @ Tim. I used Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the table to a query that counts the `auto_no`s less than or equal to each `auto_no` and update:

```
update letter l inner join (
  select t.auto_no, 
    (select count(*) from letter where auto_no like '2020-%' and auto_no <= t.auto_no) counter
  from letter t
  where auto_no like '2020-%'
) t on t.auto_no = l.auto_no
set l.auto_no = concat(left(l.auto_no, 5), lpad(t.counter, 5, '0'));
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hFRsGy717QSa7WdURBVgNm/1).
Or another option if there are no gaps between `auto_no`s:

```
update letter l cross join (
  select right(min(auto_no), 5) start_from
  from letter 
  where auto_no like '2020-%'
) t 
set l.auto_no = concat(left(l.auto_no, 5), lpad(right(l.auto_no, 5) - t.start_from + 1, 5, '0'))
where l.auto_no like '2020-%';
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hFRsGy717QSa7WdURBVgNm/2).
Results:

```
| auto_no    |
| ---------- |
| 2020-00001 |
| 2020-00002 |
| 2020-00003 |
| 2020-00004 |
| 2020-00005 |
```

Comment: @MCIT Trends check another option in my edited answer, maybe more efficient if there are no gaps between the `auto_no`s

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+, we *could* try using `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT auto_no, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY auto_no) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t2
    ON t1.auto_no = t2.auto_no
SET
    auto_no = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(auto_no, '-', 1), '-', LPAD(t2.rn, 5, '0'));
```

However, I actually recommend against doing this update.  For one thing, as soon as you add new data, you might have to update again to keep the `auto_no` sequence in order.  If you just want to *report* a row number using the `auto_no` sequence you already have, then consider building a view instead of doing an actual update.

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen. MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY auto_no) rn
    FROM letter_letter
) t2
    ON t1.auto_no = t2.auto' at line 4

Comment: @MCITTrends You're not running my code, and I didn't alias `auto_no` as `auto` in the subquery; I left it alone as `auto_no`.

Comment: @ Tim. Yes It as MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY auto_no) rn
    FROM letter_letter
) t2
    ON t1.auto_no = t2.auto_no' at line 4